# Overwriting file of the same name from a trimmed file

Tags: batch-file, rename, overwrite

I have gotten my code to work for me up until this point.  After trimming and renaming the file, if a file of the same name exists, it will not overwrite it.

This batch file is ran multiple times, so the first time it works, then the second time it cannot overwrite the file it had previously created since the newly trimmed filename is the same as the previously created filename.

Since this filename is not constant, I am unsure of how to delete it before running the command, since there will be other files with the same extension (or lack thereof) in that folder.

```
xcopy /d "%SystemDrive%\clfiles\*xp21.tap" 
"\\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD
\MS200\*xp21*" /y

set Source="\\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD\MS200"
for %%c in (%Source%\*xp21*) do (
    set MS200Trimmed=%%~nc
    set MS200Trimmed=!MS200Trimmed:~0,8!%
    ren "%%~c" !MS200Trimmed!
)
```

Comment: Use the `move` command instead. But I am not following you on how you think you cannot delete it before the rename command.  If the rename does not work you already know what the file name is.  Just issue a delete command before the rename command: `del !MS200Trimmed!`.  I am going to assume you have delayed expansion enabled.

Comment: I had previously tried the move command without luck, but possibly my formatting was incorrect.

I tried 

    for %%c in (%Source%\*xp21*) do (
        set MS200Trimmed=%%~nc
        set MS200Trimmed=!MS200Trimmed:~0,8!%
        move "%%~c" !MS200Trimmed!
    )

I am not sure how to get this to format correctly on these forums like in my initial post....

Comment: You have a trailing percent symbol in your `SET` command.

Comment: Yes I do have delayed expansion on, maybe I will post my whole code because it may make it easier.  Anyways, I have tried del !MS200Trimmed! previously without luck, I am not sure what I am missing here..

Comment: You should also quote any file names or paths.  You are not quoting the `!MS200Trimmed!` variable.  It would also help us if you should us a real world example of the file names it is failing on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is to have "del %Source%!ProbeMacro!" just before the ren.  I also think I figured out the formatting to post here finally, making my messages easier to understand :~)

```
    xcopy /d "%SystemDrive%\clfiles\*xp18.tap" 
    "\\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD

    \MS_PROBE_MACROS" /y

    ren \\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD\MS_PROBE_MACROS\*xp18.tap "M*.tap"


    set Source="\\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD\MS_PROBE_MACROS"
    for %%e in (%Source%\M*.tap) do (
        set ProbeMacro=%%~ne
        set ProbeMacro=!ProbeMacro:~0,8!%
        del %Source%\!ProbeMacro!
    ren "%%~e" "!ProbeMacro!"
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just before the "ren "%%~c" !MS200Trimmed!" line, add a delete command.

```
xcopy /d "%SystemDrive%\clfiles\*xp21.tap" 
"\\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD
\MS200\*xp21*" /y

set Source="\\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD\MS200"
for %%c in (%Source%\*xp21*) do (
    set MS200Trimmed=%%~nc
    set MS200Trimmed=!MS200Trimmed:~0,8!%
    del !MS200Trimmed! 
    ren "%%~c" !MS200Trimmed!
)
```

Comment: When I use the del !MS200Trimmed! it gives me "a duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found"

Comment: Ok, real world file names.  the filename starts as "testms20_80791025_mfg_xp21.tap" in "C:\clfiles"keeps the first 8 characters and the drops the file extension.

This outputs as "testms20" in the \\nphdata\Departments\M.E\N1040_MACHINING\OFFICE\PROGRAM_HOLD\MS200 dir.

When I use del !MS200! formatted as you have shown, it outputs testms20_80791025_mfg_xp21.tap

Comment: When I go to use the del !MS200Trimmed! it looks for the file to delete in the folder that I am running the batch from, that is why it is not working, and I am not sure why it is doing this..

Comment: Try changing it to "del %source%\!MS200Trimmed! ", to get the right path.